# Ref.current is undefined when component mount and it can not cause a re render when I need it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref

I want to make a draggable div so I created a ref to access the div so I could use it in Rxjs fromEvent operator

The problem is ref object will set after using it in fromEvent (the first time ref is not set yet) so I put it in an if statement so It only use ref when it's set.

Now dragRef.current is set but component never execute again

here is the code I'm using:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const dragRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const mouseMove = fromEvent(document, "mousedown");

    if (dragRef.current != undefined) {
        debugger;
        const mouseDown = fromEvent(dragRef.current, "mousedown");
        const mouseUp = fromEvent(dragRef.current, "mouseup");
        const mouseDrag = mouseDown.pipe(
            map((evt: MouseEvent | Event) => {
                // let offsetX = evt.clientX - dragRef.current.offsetLeft;
                // let offsetY = evt.clientY - dragRef.current.offsetTop;
                console.log(evt);
                return evt;
            })
        );
        mouseDrag.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <div className="drag" ref={dragRef}></div>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), which takes as a dependency an array of variables you want to be watching. 
So in your case, when your ref changes, you then execute the function.
Something like

```
useEffect(() => {
if (dragRef.current != undefined) {
        debugger;
        const mouseDown = fromEvent(dragRef.current, "mousedown");
        const mouseUp = fromEvent(dragRef.current, "mouseup");
        const mouseDrag = mouseDown.pipe(
            map((evt: MouseEvent | Event) => {
                // let offsetX = evt.clientX - dragRef.current.offsetLeft;
                // let offsetY = evt.clientY - dragRef.current.offsetTop;
                console.log(evt);
                return evt;
            })
        );
        mouseDrag.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
    }
}, [dragRef])
```

Comment: thanks, It works now but I don't know where I was wrong before that it was giving me a warning which said dragRef can not re render the component so remove it from useEffect dependency because it's not doing anything

Comment: @TaghiKhavari maybe this will work better then? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Answer (score 1):

here is the final Code Which works perfectly for a draggable div in React

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { map, takeUntil, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const dragRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({top: 100, left: 100})

    useEffect(() => {
        if (dragRef != null) {
            const mouseMove = fromEvent(document, "mousemove");
            //@ts-ignore
            const mouseDown = fromEvent(dragRef.current, "mousedown");
            //@ts-ignore
            const mouseUp = fromEvent(dragRef.current, "mouseup");
            const mouseDrag = mouseDown.pipe(
                mergeMap((evt: any) => {
                    //@ts-ignore
                    let offsetX = evt.clientX - dragRef!.current.offsetLeft;
                    //@ts-ignore
                    let offsetY = evt.clientY - dragRef!.current.offsetTop;
                    return mouseMove.pipe(
            map((e: any) => ({
              top: e.clientY - offsetY,
                            left: e.clientX - offsetX
                        })),
            takeUntil(mouseUp),
                    );
                })
      );

            mouseDrag.subscribe((value: any) => {
        console.log(value)
                setPosition(value)
            });
        }
    }, [dragRef]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <div className="drag" ref={dragRef} style={{top: position.top +'px', left: position.left +'px'}}></div>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```